# What is the difference between dev, media and mnt?

Tags: media

Hi there can someone tell me what is the difference between `/dev`, `/media` and `/mnt`? Are not they dictionaries for removable storage?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `/dev` directory contains special files ([device files](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file)) corresponding to physical devices or system components
- `/media` is a regular directory which by common practice is used to mount removable media like CD-ROMs, floppy disks, etc.
- `/mnt` is a regular directory which by common practice is used to mount other filesystems, usually for a short period of time

`/dev` is essential to the operating system and it cannot be removed

`/media` and `/mnt` are only a placeholder directories; removing them won't influence the operating system core operation, but might cause errors with certain applications; for example when a removable media is inserted, or when a process tries to mount a filesystem.

As an example of the difference: `/dev` contains a reference to a physical CD-ROM drive, `/mount` might contain a subdirectory through which you can access the files stored on the disc inserted to the same CD-ROM drive.